# emacs cc-mode installation issue

Tags: cc-mode

I am relatively new to emacs. I'm wanting to set up cc-mode. I'm having trouble with the process. When I initially viewed list-packages, a search brought up cc-mode, but something I've done means it is not there any more. I am using the default package source at elpa. I have downloaded and byte-compiled cc-mode into ~/.emacs.d/ and made sure it is in the load path (although I'm not confident I've done this correctly). I have tried the tests mentioned on http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/installation.php and c-version isn't recognised, just as an incremental search does not recognise 'cc-'. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`cc-mode` comes bundled with Emacs[0]. No manual installation needed. To make sure that `cc-mode` is available, just go to the scratch buffer and type `(require 'cc-mode)` place the cursor at the end of the line and press `C-x C-e`, it should echo `cc-mode` in the mini buffer.

Refer:
[0] : http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/compat.php